Powershell script to change scalling
I hope this question find you well.
I'm a work-study IT technician and I need your help with a script that doesn't work as it should in PowerShell.
Please bear in mind that this is not a graded assignment, nor is it for an exam.
So, I've created a script in PowerShell to partially automate the deployment of new workstations.
In this script, I've included a function that should set the display to 125% instead of the recommended 150%.
The script works, except that parameter -1 gives 175, parameter 0 gives 150 and neither 2 nor 3 does anything.
I'm sharing my function with you, hoping you can help.
PS: When I run it on a machine with an external screen, the external screen display changes to 125 as requested, I'm on Windows 11.
Here's my code :
`function Configure-DisplayScaling 
{
    param ([int]$scaling)
    $sourceScale = @"
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public class User32
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
            uint uiAction,
            uint uiParam,
            IntPtr pvParam,
            uint fWinIni);
    }
"@

    Add-Type -TypeDefinition $sourceScale -Language CSharp
    $apicall = [User32]
    $apicall::SystemParametersInfo(0x009F, $scaling, [IntPtr]::Zero, 1) | Out-Null
}
Configure-DisplayScaling -scaling 1`


Note that fwiw the documentation for SystemParametersInfo at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfow has a description of “Do not use” for SPI_SETLOGICALDPIOVERRIDE (the named constant for the value 0x009F in your code).

REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v LogPixels /t REG_DWORD /d 0x120 /f
This command is supposed to pass the DPI to 125, but still pass it to 175

According to the documentation for LogPixels here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dpi-related-apis-and-registry-settings?view=windows-11#table-6-hkcucontrol-paneldesktoplogpixels-values - the value for 125% scaling is decimal 120, not hex 0x120 (which is decimal 288). Have you checked the actual values stored in the registry when you manually alter the scaling and compared it to the values your REG ADD command is setting?
